# The Riemann's Zeta Function represented as a continued fraction and a question of convergence

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, continued-fractions

The Riemann zeta function can be expressed as a continued fraction as follows
\begin{align*}
\zeta(z)=\newcommand{\bigk}{\mathop{\Huge\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}\left(1-\bigk_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{-e^{-2\cdot (\coth^{-1}(2k+1))\cdot z}}{1+e^{-2\cdot (\coth^{-1}(2k+1))\cdot z}}\right)^{-1}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)
\end{align*}
thus its reciprocal as
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{{\zeta(z)}}=\newcommand{\bigk}{\mathop{\Huge\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}1-\bigk_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{-e^{-2\cdot (\coth^{-1}(2k+1)) \cdot z}}{1+e^{-2\cdot(\coth^{-1}(2k+1))\cdot z}}.\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)
\end{align*}
Proof:
Note that
\begin{align*}
\ln(n)=2 \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k+1}\left( \frac{1}{2\cdot m+1} \right)^{2k+1}
\end{align*}
and that
\begin{align*}
\coth^{-1}(2 n +1)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2k+1}\left( \frac{1}{2\cdot n+1} \right)^{2k+1}
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\ln(n)=2 \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \coth^{-1}(2 m +1)
\end{align*}
so the Riemann zeta function is expressed as
\begin{align*}
\zeta(z)=1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}e^{-2\cdot(\coth^{-1}(2k+1))\cdot z}
\end{align*}
and using [Euler's continued fraction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula) the result follows:
\begin{equation*}
  \zeta(z)= \cfrac{1}{
          1- \cfrac{e^{-2(\coth^{-1}(3))z}}{
          1+e^{-2(\coth^{-1}(3))z}- \cfrac{e^{-2(\coth^{-1}(5))z}}{
          1+e^{-2(\coth^{-1}(5))z}- \cfrac{e^{-2(\coth^{-1}(7))z}}{
          1+e^{-2(\coth^{-1}(7))z} - \ddots}}}}
\end{equation*}
which in Gauss' notation is (1)

Now consider
\begin{align*}
f(z):=\newcommand{\bigk}{\mathop{\Huge\vcenter{\hbox{K}}}}\bigk_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{-e^{-2\cdot (\coth^{-1}(2k+1))\cdot z}}{1+e^{-2\cdot(\coth^{-1}(2k+1))\cdot z}}
\end{align*}

Using the [Śleszyński–Pringsheim theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%9Aleszy%C5%84ski%E2%80%93Pringsheim_theorem) we can see that $f(z)$ converges for $\Im{z}=0$ and $\Re{z}\geq 0$. This is to say that $1/\zeta(z)$ converges for real $z\geq 0$.

My question: can a bigger region of convergence be found using the theory of continued fractions?

Comment: Is this
$
\mathop{\large{\bf K}}_{k=1}^\infty
$
notation standard?  The only other place I've seen it is in other recent questions from A.Neves.

Comment: @Noam: it's somewhat standard in CF literature. I'm told it's originally Gauss's.


Comment: I don't really understand Gauss's notation. Why is it not $\zeta(z)=\left(1+\bigk\cdots\right)^{-1}$?

Answer (score 14):

(Too long for a comment.)

There's a (somewhat) simpler (Eulerian) continued fraction:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^s}=1+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \prod_{j=2}^k \left(1-\frac1{j}\right)^s=\cfrac1{1-\cfrac{\left(1-\frac12\right)^s}{1+\left(1-\frac12\right)^s-\cfrac{\left(1-\frac13\right)^s}{1+\left(1-\frac13\right)^s-\cfrac{\left(1-\frac14\right)^s}{1+\left(1-\frac14\right)^s-\cdots}}}}\;\;\;\;\;\;$$

but as you can see from comparing successive convergents of this continued fraction and the successive partial sums of the Dirichlet series, it's not terribly useful.

Also,

$$e^{-2z\,\mathrm{arcoth}(2k+1)}=\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^z$$

so your CF could certainly be simplified a fair bit...