# Continued fraction representation of Zeta

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, riemann-zeta-function, continued-fractions

[A question at math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/745023/28555) is asking for references.  The fraction is quite nice!  Check it out and post some references if you know of any.

I found this at [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4015), but it doesn't apply to Zeta.

Comment: google _riemann zeta continued fraction_: a paper [`by S.Apodaca`](https://www.math.washington.edu/~morrow/336_10/papers/shawn.pdf), another one [`by CVIJOVIC AND KLINOWSKI`](http://www.ams.org/proc/1997-125-09/S0002-9939-97-04102-6/S0002-9939-97-04102-6.pdf), a [`MO post`](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84108/the-riemanns-zeta-function-represented-as-a-continued-fraction-and-a-question-o), a [`Wolfram demo tool`](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ApproximatingTheRiemannZetaFunctionWithContinuedFractions/).  Above inks perhaps not related to MSE question but there are more google results.

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko, thanks for the suggestions. I spent a few hours and didn't find any continued fractions that used only prime numbers.  It's looking like Neves's fraction is unique.

Comment: @Fred Kline, I found that H. J. Brothers is submiting an article with the tittle "The Euler zeta function, continued fractions, and pi". See [here](http://www.harlanjbrothers.com/#articles).

Comment: @A.Neves, Looks like we have to wait to learn more. No preprint on arXiv. Make your comment an answer an I'll sign off with bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that H. J. Brothers is submiting an article with the tittle "*The Euler zeta function, continued fractions, and pi*" see [here](http://www.harlanjbrothers.com/#articles).